# support render props of react router in route hoc

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router-v4

I am writing a HOC for public route and private route. If the route is private and the user is authenticated then let him/her enter that page else redirect to login component. If the route is public and the user is not authenticated then show the page and also show the login page if the user is not authenticated but user is authenticated and still goes to login page then redirect the user to root page. This is working fine. But if i use the render instead of component, then it does not work. I could make it work only if i pass the component from the props called component of react-router.

How can i make it work if user user render props?

Here is my code

```
<Switch>
  <PrivateRoute
    exact
    path="/"
    render={() => <Home name="something" />} {/* this does not work */}
  />
  <PrivateRoute exact path="/demo" component={Demo} />
  <PublicRoute restricted={true} path="/auth" component={Authentication} />
</Switch>
```

PublicRoute.js

```
const PublicRoute = ({component: Component, restricted, ...rest}) => {
  return (
    <Route
      {...rest}
      render={props =>
        isLogin() && restricted ? <Redirect to="/" /> : <Component {...props} />
      }
    />
  )
}
```

PrivateRoute.js

```
const PrivateRoute = ({component: Component, ...rest}) => {
  return (
    <Route
      {...rest}
      render={props =>
        isLogin() ? <Component {...props} /> : <Redirect to="/auth/login" />
      }
    />
  )
}
```

Also if there is any additional things to improve, please do suggest me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that in your custom routes you are always using the `component` prop. So when passing the `render` prop it is overruled by the one in your custom route and thus trying to render the provided `component`.

When you modify it like the function below, it will work. It also extracts the `render` prop and if it's a function it will use that instead of the `component` prop.

```
const PrivateRoute = ({component: Component, render, ...rest}) => {
    const renderContent = props => {
        if (!fakeAuth.isAuthenticated) {
            return (
                <Redirect
                    to={{
                        pathname: "/login",
                        state: { from: props.location }
                    }}
                />
            )
        }
        return (typeof render === 'function') ? render(props) : <Component {...props} />
    }

    return (
        <Route {...rest} render={renderContent} />
    );
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for this wonderful solution. I have one confusion. If its not okay to ask here, I am sorry but my question is like now user can either pass component or render props so when checking the prop-types it can be either component as required or render props as required and if i validate both as required then it will be a problem because i can only pass either component prop or render prop.

Comment: You can write your own validation logic, check https://stackoverflow.com/a/42284491/829493 for more info on that.

Comment: Thanks I will look at it.