# How to require that one of two properties is passed with PropTypes?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-proptypes

Let's say that I have some props in a component and the name of a property might vary.
For example, the property could be called "release" or it could be called "release_date" depending on several factors like which JSON API I'm consuming. Is there a way to use the PropTypes to mandate that one of these is definitely passed, and furthermore that it's a string.

I'm not asking how to require that one property has one of two values or one of two types. When searching around for an answer to my question, that's the only thing I could find.

In my case, I have something like

```
SomeComponent.propTypes = {
  id: PropTypes.number.isRequired,
  title: PropTypes.string.isRequired,

// it should be required that one of these two is passed and is a string
  release_date: PropTypes.string,
  release: PropTypes.string,

// likewise here but with number
  vote_average: PropTypes.number,
  score: PropTypes.number,
};
```

Can you achieve this using PropTypes? Thanks

Comment: Why not use a single property and convert your JSON response to the correct format?

Comment: @Reyno That's a good point, and it's kind of complicated / I'm oversimplifying the example, but in any case, regardless of whether or not this architecture is sound, is this kind of thing possible within framework of PropTypes?

Comment: @Reyno I did ultimately do what you suggested, but would still like to know if this is possible. If not, that's okay too

Comment: Yes this is possible according to [At least one required prop in React](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42284076/at-least-one-required-prop-in-react), though I didn't test it (yet)